# Why does my Docker build speed up if I change how I copy files?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file looks like this:

```
.
.
WORKING /app
COPY ..
RUN npm install
.
.
```

It works well but takes lots of time to be built every time (over 7 mins). After some research, I understood I have to optimize the Dockerfile so that it uses **Cache**. So, I've written it like this:

```
.
.
WORKING /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY ..
.
.
```

Now, it builds much faster (less than 1 min). My question is "why exactly"?

---

If Linux can understand a file is either modified or not while copying it to either override it or read it from the cache, then I expected that both `COPY ..` and `COPY package*.json .` have the same behavior. Why only `COPY package*.json .` uses cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every line in your docker file results in a new 'layer'. Docker will keep all these layers. If nothing changed in your directory, it doesn't need to run `COPY . .` because it saved the layer from the last time it ran.

`RUN npm install` takes a while, but it only results in a new state *if* your dependencies changed. (you installed a new package, or updated one).

If `COPY . .` needs to re-run (because you updated your code), every line under there also needs to re-run. Because you likely change your code more often than your dependencies, it makes sense to install dependencies earlier.

If do you ever add a new npm package, you will see that Docker will re-run every line from `RUN npm install` onward.